# iPhone testing checklists

Tags: iphone, stress-testing

I need a checklist for checking iPhone applications. Can anyone help me on this with some usefull links or data? 
:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is your iPhone app testing strategy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860889/what-is-your-iphone-app-testing-strategy)

Answer (score 1):

- Test with build and analyze
- Test with Performance Tool - esp. memory leak
- Run on iPhone different versions and device, iPhone 3GS, 4, with iOS3.1.3, 3.2, 4.0 etc.
- Run it removing the SIM
- Without any network connection
- In airplane mode
- Change timezone, localization ...

Comment: Can u suggest some Performence tool for iPhone

Comment: its in xcode. In the menu, Menu > Build > Build and Analyze, And in the Menu > Run > Run with performance tool